# Output of sh for loop is messed up

Tags: sh

I am currently writing a script which should check the ATA security status for each device listed in a file.

The ATA security status gets checked with the Command `smartctl -g security "$drive" | grep -c "ATA Security is:.*NOT FROZEN"`, which outputs 0 (frozen) or 1 (not frozen) and has been tested.

The script is currently looking like this:

```sh
# get newline as Seperator
IFS=$(echo)
# get drives
drives=$(cat ./sd-freeze.conf)

# check status for each drive
for drive in $drives
do  
    frozen=$(smartctl -g security "$drive" | grep -c "ATA Security is:.*NOT FROZEN")
    echo "$drive"
    echo "$frozen"
done
```

sd-freeze.conf contains this:

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sdb
```

The output should be:

```
/dev/sda
1
/dev/sdb
1
```

But somehow, it is:

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sdb
0
```

Does anyone know why the order of the output is messed up (both devices are not frozen)?

Comment: I found out that the default value of $IFS already contains a newline and IFS=newline is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> # get newline as Seperator
> IFS=$(echo)
> ```

`$(...)` strips any trailing newlines from the string. This line actually sets `IFS=''` rather than `IFS=$'\n'` as desired. The means that the unquoted `$drives` below isn't being split at all. The loop only iterates a single time over the entire `$drives` string.

A possible fix is to set `IFS=$'\n'` to get that newline in there, but really, it's best not to override `IFS` globally. As the [wise Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081211-00/?p=19873) says, "Don’t use global state to manage a local problem."

To read a set of lines into an array I would use `readarray`. That way the rest of the script isn't potentially impacted.

```
readarray -t drives < sd-freeze.conf

# check status for each drive
for drive in "${drives[@]}"
do  
    frozen=$(smartctl -g security "$drive" | grep -c "ATA Security is:.*NOT FROZEN")
    echo "$drive"
    echo "$frozen"
done
```

Comment: Better yet, [use a `while` loop](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) to iterate over the contents of a file, which doesn't require reading the entire file in to memory at once.